# NSTask / Process deprecated methods and properties

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, nstask

In the most recent Apple documentation both **[`NSTask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstask?language=objc)** and **[`Process`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process)** have several *deprecated* methods and properties, although there's nothing marked with an **[`API Availability Macro`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-Foundation-OSX10.12/index.html)**.

**Instance Properties**

```
@property(copy) NSString *launchPath;
@property(copy) NSString *currentDirectoryPath;

var launchPath: String? { get set }
var currentDirectoryPath: String { get set }
```

**Instance Methods**

```
- (void)launch;

func launch()
```

**Type Methods**

```
+ (NSTask *)launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:(NSString *)path 
                             arguments:(NSArray<NSString *> *)arguments; 

class func launchedProcess(launchPath path: String, 
                 arguments: [String]) -> Process
```

There seemingly are no replacements available, so what gives?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> There seemingly are no replacements available

There are, the API is now URL related

**Instance Properties**

```
@property(copy) NSURL *executableURL;
@property(copy) NSURL *currentDirectoryURL;

var executableURL: URL? { get set }
var currentDirectoryURL: URL? { get set }
```

**Instance Methods**

```
- (BOOL)launchAndReturnError:(out NSError * _Nullable *)error;

func run() throws
```

**Type Methods**

```
+ (NSTask *)launchedTaskWithExecutableURL:(NSURL *)url 
                                arguments:(NSArray<NSString *> *)arguments 
                                    error:(out NSError * _Nullable *)error 
                       terminationHandler:(void (^)(NSTask *))terminationHandler;

class func run(_ url: URL, 
               arguments: [String], 
               terminationHandler: ((Process) -> Void)? = nil) throws -> Process
```

Comment: Is there someplace that mentions this change? Thanks!

Comment: AFAIR It was mentioned in a WWDC video.

Comment: what WWDC video?

Comment: @user426132 What's new in Cocoa, WWDC 2017, mentioned in a subclause.

Comment: It's mid 2019 and still the XCode docs don't have any overview or discussion notes. And the deprecated functions don't point to the new APIs to use either. Thanks @vadian for pointing these out.